# meteor and lodash each

Tags: meteor, lodash

I am trying to call **_.each**  function in meteor server method .
As you know the each method has a function that will be executed for each item in the list 
My problem that I can’t use the **bindenviroment** function in a correct way 
I have the below error 
**Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.**

Here is my code

```
'fillSampleData': function() {
var fs = require('fs');
var base = process.env.PWD
projectsCollction.remove({});
changeSetsCollction.remove({});
var readFileAndInsert = function() {
  fs.readFile(base + '/server/json/projects.json', 'utf8',
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      //loop th
      _.each(json, Meteor.bindEnvironment((eer, projctItem) => {
        var project_Id = projectsCollction.insert(
          projctItem)
        console.log(`projict ${project_Id}`);

      }));
    }
    //----------------------------
  );
}
  readFileAndInsert()
}
```

=============**Edit**=======

I have changed the code but the same result

```
  'fillSampleData': function() {

var fs = require('fs');
var base = process.env.PWD
projectsCollction.remove({});
changeSetsCollction.remove({});
var myFunction = function(passedItem) {
  Meteor.bindEnvironment((eer, passedItem) => {
    var project_Id = projectsCollction.insert(
      passedItem)
    console.log(`project ${project_Id}`);
  })
}
var readFileandInsert = function() {
  fs.readFile(base + '/server/json/projects.json', 'utf8',
    function(err,
      data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      _.each(json, (item) => {
        myFunction(item);
      });
    }
    //----------------------------
  );
}
readFileandInsert();
}
```

the error stack is

```
W20161022-07:22:26.840(3)? (STDERR) /home/mohammed/poly/synthesis-  demo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteor.js:1060
W20161022-07:22:26.844(3)? (STDERR)     throw new Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. " +
W20161022-07:22:26.848(3)? (STDERR)     ^
W20161022-07:22:26.853(3)? (STDERR)
W20161022-07:22:26.855(3)? (STDERR) Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.
W20161022-07:22:26.860(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor._nodeCodeMustBeInFiber (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:9:1)
W20161022-07:22:26.863(3)? (STDERR)     at Object.Meteor.bindEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:85:1)
W20161022-07:22:26.865(3)? (STDERR)     at myFunction (server/main.js:42:14)
W20161022-07:22:26.867(3)? (STDERR)     at server/main.js:56:13
W20161022-07:22:26.868(3)? (STDERR)     at arrayEach (/home/mohammed/poly/synthesis-demo/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:451:11)
W20161022-07:22:26.870(3)? (STDERR)     at Function.forEach (/home/mohammed/poly/synthesis-demo/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:8634:14)
W20161022-07:22:26.872(3)? (STDERR)     at server/main.js:55:13
W20161022-07:22:26.873(3)? (STDERR)     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

_.each will only pass the element to the function, you are trying to pass two. You'll need to use a function to do it

```
_.each(json,(item) => {
    myFunction(item);
});
```

and declare this function:

```
var myFunction = function(passedItem) {
Meteor.bindEnvironment((eer, passedItem) => {
    var project_Id = projectsCollction.insert(
        passedItem)
    console.log(`projict ${project_Id}`);
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you put it in a plunker or fiddle or similar?

Comment: @mohammedbarqawi I'm sorry, just pasting the above code into a plunker doesn't help me. I am willing to help, but you should provide something that will let me reproduce your problem without doing a heap of work. Perhaps you could share your meteor project with me? You can put it on github and share that, or if you prefer to keep it private you could use bitbucket

Comment: I hank you for help , I found that the CB for file read should have bindenvirment

Answer (score 0):

I found that the bindEnvironment function was in a wrong place

```
  fs.readFile(base + '/server/json/projects.json', 'utf8',
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err,
      data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      _.each(json, (item) => {
        var project_Id = projectsCollction.insert(
          item)
        console.log(`project ${project_Id}`);

      });
    })
```